# left to right evaluation

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am trying to carry out left to right evaluation in C. No order of precedence whatsoever. So 5+3*2 should be 16. I know how to do that with 2 numbers and an operator, however, I cannot figure out how to do the same thing for an expression like 2+4-5+2.

This is what I have for 2 numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20
int main(void)
{

char exp[SIZE];
int ans,c, i=0;
int length;

printf("Enter your expression: ");
fgets(exp, 20, stdin);
length = strlen(exp);
--length;

for(int j=0; j<length; j++)
{
    while (exp[i]!='\n')
    {
//        putchar(exp[i]);
        i++;
        switch (exp[i])
        {

                case '+':
                ans = (exp[i]-'0') + (exp[2]-'0');
                printf("The answer is %d\n", ans);
                break;
            case '-':
                ans = (exp[0]-'0') - (exp[2]-'0');
                printf("The answer is %d\n", ans);
                break;
            case '*':
                ans = (exp[0]-'0') * (exp[2]-'0');
                printf("The answer is %d\n", ans);
                break;
            case '/':
                ans = (exp[0]-'0') / (exp[2]-'0');
                printf("The answer is %d\n", ans);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
exit(0);

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: make your first number your `ans`, then just keep doing calculations with `ans`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming alternating numbers and operators with single-character numbers (which seems to be what you assumed), a minimal implementation similar to your original implementation is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20

int main(void) {
    char exp[SIZE];
    int ans, length, i;

    printf("Enter your expression: ");
    fgets(exp, 20, stdin);
    ans = exp[0] - '0';
    length = strlen(exp) - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < length && exp[i] != '\n'; i++) {
        switch (exp[i]) {
            case '+':
                ans += exp[i+1] - '0';
                break;
            case '-':
                ans -= exp[i+1] - '0';
                break;
            case '*':
                ans *= exp[i+1] - '0';
                break;
            case '/':
                ans /= exp[i+1] - '0';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("The answer is %d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh so I just had to modify my answer. I get it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> As per your given example, assumed that each number will be single digit number.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20
int main(void)
{
    char exp[SIZE];
    int ans,c, i=0;
    int length,j;

    printf("Enter your expression: ");
    fgets(exp, 20, stdin);
    length = strlen(exp);
    char ch;
    ans = exp[i]-'0';
    i++;
    while (i <= length)
    {
        switch (exp[i])
        {
            case '+':
                i++;
                ans += (exp[i]-'0');
                break;
            case '-':
                i++;
                ans -=(exp[i]-'0');
                break;
            case '*':
                i++;
                ans *=(exp[i]-'0');
                break;
            case '/':
                i++;
                ans /= (exp[i]-'0');
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        i++;
        //printf("The answer is %d\n", ans);
    }
    printf("The answer is %d\n", ans);
    exit(0);
}
```